# MSBuild and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, jenkins, msbuild

I am trying to accomplish MSBuild for an out-of-the-box MVC4 project, in order to eventually use it combined with Jenkins in my real life application. The very **not** detailed tutorial I've tried following is [Here](http://www.jayway.com/2012/10/17/a-simple-continuous-integration-and-deployment-workflow-with-asp-net-mvc-github-and-jenkins/#comment-5306)

First, is there any alternative, open sourced, way to compile + deploy ASP.NET app? - it must be pluggable into Jenkins.

Second, I keep getting many types of errors, none of them are easy to debug, since valuable documentation doesn't popped up easily on google. Any good "auto generated" tool or good **short** manuals to get started with it?

Third, concrete errors: 
1.
 `Build started 7/15/2014 10:47:13 AM.
     1>Project "C:\WebSites\jenkinsDeployment\Jenkins\TestJenkinsGit.sln" on no
       de 1 (default targets).
     1>C:\WebSites\jenkinsDeployment\Jenkins\TestJenkinsGit.sln.metaproj : erro
       r MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "Debug|HPD" is invalid.
       Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration an
       d Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=De
       bug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank to use the de
       fault solution configuration. [C:\WebSites\jenkinsDeployment\Jenkins\Tes
       tJenkinsGit.sln]
     1>Done Building Project "C:\WebSites\jenkinsDeployment\Jenkins\TestJenkins
       Git.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.`

2.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\MyApp-Test\workspace>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
\MSBuild.exe /p:DeployOnBuild= true /p:PublishProfile=Test;SolutionDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\
jobs\MyApp-Test\workspace /m /p:Configuration=Release "/p:Platform=Any CPU" DeployIt.sln              
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.33440                                                    
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.34014]                                                   
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.                                             

MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.                                           
Switch: Files                                                                                         

For switch syntax, type "MSBuild /help"
```

And many many more...

Answer (score 0):

1. There is [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility). Everything is pluggable into Jenkins since it can run an executable, hence you can plug in MSPaint if you wanted to.
2. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416514.aspx), the javadocs of anything .NET including MVC. There is also dedicated [asp.net/mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc).
3. 1. If you're passing a custom platform (`HPD`) to an `.sln` then all `.csproj` in that solution have to have it, otherwise click on solution in Studio, go to Properties > Configuration Properties and check your [default] project platform settings.
   2. `/p` flag shouldn't be in quotes, all paths with spaces should, `DeployOnBuild` shouldn't have a space before value and so on. Remote onto the build server, copy/paste the command from the error log and fix it till it runs manually before plugging back it into Jenkins or anywhere else; better yet make it build locally first from command line regardless of the CI server.